# Orthogonal projection

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given the Hilbert space $H=\mathbb{L}^2 ([0,1])$ endowed with the canonical scalar product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$, as well as the orthogonal projection $p_n:H\mapsto H$ defined by:
$$p_n f=n\sum_{k=1}^n \langle f,\mathbb{1}_{I(k)} \rangle \mathbb{1}_{I(k)},$$
where the intervals $I(k)$ are defined by $I(k)=\left[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}\right]$ for all $k\in\{1,...,n\}$, I would like to prove that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|p_n f - f\|=0,$$
where $\|.\|$ is the norm induced by the canonical scalar product $\langle .,. \rangle$. My first idea was to develop everything as follows:
$$ \|p_n f - f\|^2=\langle f,f \rangle-2\langle  f,p_n f \rangle + \langle p_n f,p_n f \rangle=\|f\|^2-n\sum_{k=1}^n \langle f,\mathbb{1}_{I(k)} \rangle^2.$$
I now need to show that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\sum_{k=1}^n \langle f,\mathbb{1}_{I(k)} \rangle^2=\|f\|^2,$$
but at this point I am not sure how to move forward!

If $f$ is continuous to start with, is this result in any way obvious (I can then extend the result to $H$ by density)? Any ideas of references to literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd try taking a nice (in a dense subset of $H$) $f$ first and then use density.

Comment: I was thinking in something like $||p_nf-f||\leq ||p_nf-p_ng||+||p_ng-g||+||g-f||$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have defined:
$$
   p_nf = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}f(y)dy\right]\chi_{[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]}(x)
$$
The linear operator $p_n$ is an orthogonal projection operator onto the linear span of the orthonormal set $\left\{\sqrt{n}\chi_{[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]}\right\}_{k=1}^{n}$. Hence, $p_n^2=p_n$ and $\|p_nf\| \le \|f\|$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and let $f \in L^2$ be real. Then there exists a real continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\|f-g\| < \epsilon/2$. Because $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
               |g(x)-g(y)| < \epsilon/2 \mbox{ whenever } |x-y| < \delta.
$$
Choose $N$ large enough that $1/N < \delta$. Then,
$$
   g\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \le n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}g(y)dy \le g\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)+\frac{\epsilon}{2},
\;\;\; n \ge N, \\
     |p_ng-g(x)| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2},\;\;\; x \in [0,1],\;\; n \ge N, \\
    \|p_ng-g\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon,\;\;\; n \ge N.
$$
Because $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, then
$$
                 \lim_{n}\|p_ng-g\|_{L^2}=0,\;\;\; g\in C[0,1].
$$
So the desired result holds for continuous functions.

Finally, if $f \in L^2$, and if $\epsilon > 0$ is given, then there exists $g\in C[0,1]$ such that $\|f-g\|<\epsilon/3$ and $N \ge 0$ such that $\|p_n g-g\|<\epsilon/3$ whenever $n \ge N$, from which it follows that
\begin{align}
        \|p_nf -f \| & \le \|p_n(f-g)\|+\|p_ng-g\|+\|g-f\| \\
        & \le \|f-g\|+\|p_ng-g\|+\|f-g\| < \epsilon,\;\; n \ge N.
\end{align}
Therefore, $\lim_n\|p_nf -f \|=0$.

Comment: many thanks for your detailed answer. Just one thing I am not quite sure about, Do you mean $f\in\mathbb{L}^2$ real and continuous on line 5?

Comment: or rather, in your first case, can't we just use your argument for $f$ continuous (without any approximation via $g$)?

Comment: @user223935 : You have to show $\lim_n p_n g = g$ for all $g$ in dense subspace $\mathcal{M}$ of $L^2$. The result follows then because $\|p_n\|\le 1$ for all $n$. So I chose $\mathcal{M}=C[0,1]$, which is dense in $L^2[0,1]$. And $p_ng \rightarrow g$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ for continuous $g$, which definitely implies $L^2$ convergence. That's the idea.

Comment: Yes I understand the approximating procedure via continuous functions. But in your first case (proving the result for continuous functions $f$), why do we need to approximate via $g$ (i.e my understanding is that we need to approximate $f\in L^2$ by continuous $g$ only in the second case)?

Comment: @user223935 : I made a major edit, and messed up the beginning of the second paragraph, which I have now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: ok thanks man, everything is clear now!

Comment: Just one other thing, when you write $g\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \le n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}g(y)dy \le g\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and then multiply the inequality by $\mathbb{1}_{I(k)}(x)$ and then sum over $k$, doesn't this give $\sum_{k=1}^n g(k/n)\mathbb{1}_{I(k)}(x)$ instead of $g(x)$?

Comment: @user223935 : That was a sample point. Actually, $g(x)-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \le n \cdots \le g(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $x \in [\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]$. Or you can use the fact that $|g(k/n)-g(x)| < \epsilon/2$ for $x \in [\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]$. Lots of ways to see the resulting inequality.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation!